# How can I quit the bash when I acident run while with pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I run the this command

```
$(while true;do echo Something && sleep 0.01;  done;) | cat
```

Now I can not exit by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or background it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and `ps aux` can't tell me which bash it is.How can I quit that bash ?

**EDIT**

I narrow donw the pid by find the cwd `pgrep bash| (while read -r line; do  lsof -p $line|grep cwd|grep EXPECTED_CWD && echo "GOT $line"; done;)`,finally kill that process.[There](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357) is easier way to find that, but no `/proc` on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the terminal can help.
If you are using CLI-only os then you can switch to different terminal using Ctrl + Alt + F1 keys.

There you can use who or ps commands to get process-id and kill it.

ps -ef will list all processes.
you can kill second last bash process, as that will be the last command that you executed. 
Note : process id assignment in linux is always greater than old one.

Comment: A bash in iterm2, oh yes, I can drag that out and close.

Comment: All bash are opened long time ago. kill second last bash may not accurate.

Comment: hey wener thats why i mentioned the note. i assume you have one working terminal, and that command is the last you hit and is stuck. Now if you switch to new terminal and hit ps -ef there, the second last will be the exact, and moreover it will be followed by cat process in list.

Comment: I have four iterm2 tab,almost 20 bash, can not remember the order I open them, so the second last bash process is probably not that bash.

Comment: PS, pid assignment is not **always** greater than the previous one.  If your system starts enough processes, it will wrap around back to the bottom of the range of pids.

Answer (score -1):

you're able to execute your commands with `&`  symbol in the end of the command to run this command in background

In your case command looks like:

```
$(while true;do echo Something && sleep 0.01;  done;) | cat &
```

It will show the process ID, and you'll be able to kill it, when you want

Comment: sudo kill -9 <process_id>

Comment: @pivanchy -1 You didn't read the question at all. He doesn't know how to obtain the process ID.

Comment: @Bernhard, I wrote, that after running the command it gives a PID of this process

Comment: @pivanchy I have 20 bash process now, I ran the command in one of them, I don't want to `killall bash`,and I don't know which(pid) bash it is.

Comment: @wener, as a possible way, you can try to use `pstree` utility for chechink  what the process is doing

Comment: Tried pstree, On mac I have to `brew install pstree` first,but not help too much,because there is so many bash processes.